# Heat creation of computer electronics

Tags: thermodynamics, electric-circuits

The first thing I learnt in physics was that whenever anything happens heat is created. Irrespective of the process.

With that in mind, electronics clearly create heat (ohmic heating I think?). But when it comes to computer chips etc., I'm at a loss to identify if any energy *isn't* lost to heat. Lets say I take a small electronics board that takes a few images and stores them to a memory card. There's no physical movement of any parts, so there's no kinetic energy, there's no sound, etc. Does all the energy become heat? If so does that mean if my board requires 5 watts to run then I'm producing 5 W of heat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every memory device stores a little bit of energy in order to store information - whether it be aligned magnetic domains, a charged capacitor, or the state of a flip-flop that has a small amount of current flowing through it (to mention just three possible memory devices).

That said, if you change the state of memory it is possible that you increase or decrease the amount of energy stored (for example, if a discharged capacitor represents '`0`, it is possible you change the amount of stored energy by writing all zeros to memory).

So no - it is not completely accurate that "all energy used by the computer is emitted as heat". But it is awfully close, even in the above case.

Comment: Plus, if you include the display, some energy is used to create light. Which gets us into the question of exactly what EM radiation is heat and what isn't, but I think the idea is clear.